# App performace with million tables in a database in PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: postgresql-9.4

We have a requirement for our application in which single database with 1 million tables(which spread across multiple schemas) with average 100 requests / second and we are planning to use version 9.4.

My Questions

1. Can PG deal with 1 million tables. Does huge number of tables slow down the performance any way
2. Query planner will query system tables like pg_catalog for every query. Will it cause any perf issues.
3. Will there be any significant performance degradation on lookup of data files(million) since located in single directory.

Senthil

Comment: You should be able to get this information using google or the PG homepage/documentation. And performance stuff usually does not only depend on the software you use, but on the hardware as well. I doubt a "Raspberry Pi" would be able to handle this load... a main frame on the other hand might be able to.

Comment: You need to improve the hardware first. I am using PostgreSQL 9.4 and it takes for the web page to load 1 lakh data for about 30 secs in the network. That too, this db was under testing only.